# Are there best Practices for saving API Keys & Secret into the Database?

Tags: database, laravel, api, security

I'm working on a small Laravel Project where users can sign up and connect to different APIs. I know API Keys shouldn't be saved in the Database but Every user has his own private API-Key and I can not Hardcode it to the .env file. I thought about saving the Key & Secret in different Tables and also encrypt them with the APP_KEY.

Are there better ways?

Thanks in advance for any feedback

Comment: You might want to look at Laravel Passport. https://laravel.com/docs/passport

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- First You Need To Create Model & Table

Step 1:(Create Model & Migration)

```
Php artisan make:model ApiKey -m
```

=> Model Name

- ApiKey

=> Columns Name

- id, user_id, api_key, api_secret, created_at, updated_at

Step 3:(To Store Data)

Web.Php

```
Route::post(‘user-details’,’UserController@storeApiDetails’)—>name(‘user-details’);
```

UserController

```
use App\ApiKey;

public function storeApiDetails(Request $request){
    $request[‘user_id’]      =  Auth::id();
    $request[‘api_key’]      =  bcrypt($request->api_key);
     $request[‘api_secret’]   =  bcrypt($request->api_secret);
    $data = ApiKey::create($request->all());
    
    if($data->save()){
        dd(“Success & Redirect To View File”);
    }else{
        dd(“Failed”);
    }
}
```