# Where to store rotating api keys/passwords in Laravel

Tags: laravel, configuration, laravel-artisan, .env

I'm writing an API with Laravel 9 and I use the AWS Secrets Manager to get secrets like a database password. I can't write it in the .env since every 4 hours or so, the password will change so i need to pull the new one from AWS. So config:cache is not an option, since  rerun config:cache in production will delete the bootstrap/cache/config.php file which make the database unavailable till the new file is created. This maybe only takes a few seconds but this is unacceptable for an API.

I tried to override the config:cache command but to not delete the old file but rather create a temp file load all the keys and then replace the old file by moving the new on to the right place. My Plan was to config:cache every hour by a cron job. But as long as the file is not deleted laravel refuses to read the files in the config folder, and getting the config from somewhere else.

Is there a recommended way to hold such passwords/keys. It can be a total different aproach, i just need something that works, and is not super hacky. Since we use only a remote database storing in the databse is not an option to, since than we'll add a round trip to the database each call. So storing locally would be ideal. It felt like everyone in the internet puts their keys in the .env and caches them at deployment and is happy with it :D

Answer (score 0):

I am storing it in DB.

Table name: dbo.setting

Example:

```
key                     | value    | updated_at
OpenExchangeRatesApiKey | o2a..sg8 | 2023-01-01 00:00:00.000
SendgridApiKey          | sas..7dr | 2020-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Check also this:
[Are there best Practices for saving API Keys & Secret into the Database?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66922342/are-there-best-practices-for-saving-api-keys-secret-into-the-database?rq=1)

Comment: Do you use a local Database?
Since adding a remote Datebase would then add the same roundtrip for each call. which we want to avoid with storing in the local files, like the config:cache